# VBA How to retrieve webpage with domain login

Tags: vba, authentication, dns

I have a customer profile website which display customer details for each CustomerID. The website require domain login.
Now I need to create an excel report file to extract the list of computer details.
I try to use vba code to Post/Get to get the website content.
My problem is that, the return HTML always is the 401 Error (because I cannot using vba to pass the domain authenticate even I have account)
Could anyone help to login domain from vba?

Thanks

Comment: This depends greatly on the way the website handles the login. Some accept a string like http://mycompany.com?user=xxxxx&pw=yyyy... Could you find out what your site does (or what cms you have?)

Comment: this is not any CMS website, this is developed website from our partner

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that you need to know what kind of login your site uses